# Asp.net Webapplication on a multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deployment, web-farm

I was wondering what do i need to get my asp.net web application installed on multiple server, having them working as a one piece.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a load-balancer which will automatically route the requests between your different servers hosting your application.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx

Comment: But what about the DBs any idea ?